# c# - Remove every n-th character from a string

Tags: c#

I have an encrypted that I want to decrypt

What I want to do is remove every 1st and nth letter in this case it's every 4 characters character in the string and repeat the process until the string is empty.

Encrypted String

**N**GGO**E**UIU**V**NVU**E**NEP**R**AYX

From the encrypted string if you take out the first letter and every 4th letter you get the never

Decrypted String

```
NEVERGUNNAGIVEYOUPX
```

Comment: Hi, Please can you see this post 'how to ask a good question': https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  What have you tried so far (also how - with a code example), and what problems are you having. We're not here to do your homework for you, but we will help if you've made an effort and are stuck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Approach with `while()` loop and remembering the current index and the offset (0-3)

```
string input = "NGGOEUIUVNVUENEPRAYX";
int index = 0, offest = 0;
while (offest < 4)
{
    Console.Write(input[index + offest]);
    index += 4;
    if (index >= input.Length)
    {
        index = 0;
        offest++;
    }       
};
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/T1SkEn